# Is there any valid conversion from const char** to const void **?

Tags: c++

I wonder if there is any valid conversion from `const char**` to `const void**` in C++. I cannot even do it with `reinterpret_cast`, so I wonder how I can do it without using C-style casts.

Example:

```
void foo(const void** v) {
}
int main() {
    const char* d = nullptr;
    foo(&d);
}
```

Comment: Such a conversion would practically never make sense. Converting to `void*` may make sense, but what do you expect the value and type of the `void**` result to represent?

Comment: @user17732522 Because it can easily happens. I will update question with example.

Comment: In your example, how would `f` try to use `v`? If it tries to dereference it and access the pointed-to object, while `v` is actually a pointer to a `const char*` rather than a `void*` (regardless of how you managed the cast), then the access is an aliasing violation and has undefined behavior. The function must be given a pointer to an actual `void*` (or `const void*`) object in that case.

Comment: Sure, use `memcpy`.   Totally unsafe, but so is treating a const as non-const.

Comment: @user17732522 it will allocate `*v` and then `memcpy` into it. It is fairly common in `C` libraries(OpenSSL in my case). If you want to write a wrapper over some C functions, you can encounter these types of conversions.

Comment: @user17732522 The address of an untyped pointer?

Comment: Does too [work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/3GjKKosr9) with `reinterpret_cast` (setting aside for a moment the question of whether it makes sense). You claim it didn't work for you - what happened when you tried?

Comment: "_it will allocate *v_": `*v = malloc(/*...*/)` is an aliasing violation in both C++ and C if `*v` is actually a `char*` rather than a `void*`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ouch I made a mistake and forgot to add const to my conversion. Sorry, reinterpret_cast works. But is there any other way, I prefer not to use it in my code if possible.

Comment: Why? I wonder why you need this. Even implicit conversion of pointers to `void*` is [disputable](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#cpl1-prefer-c-to-c) in C++.

Comment: @MarekR I'm stucked to OpenSSL library and it has that conversion.

Comment: Surely there must be examples explaining how to correctly use whatever OpenSSL function you are trying to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast a `char**` to a `void**` with `reinterpret_cast` and if either one also has a `const` somewhere you can still make the conversion work with a `const_cast` first (or after) the `reinterpret_cast` to add/remove the `const` qualifiers as necessary, while leaving `char`/`void` unchanged.

However, the resulting pointer can't be used. For example:

```
void foo(const void** v) {
    *v = /*...*/; // 1
    // or
    const void* x = *v; // 2
}
int main() {
    const char* d = nullptr;
    foo(reinterpret_cast<const void**>(&d));
}
```

Here both `//1` and `//2` have undefined behavior (in both C and C++) because `*v` is a lvalue of type `const void*` while referring to an object of type `const char*`. These are not compatible types and are not listed as exceptions to the general aliasing rule in either C or C++. Therefore `*v` may not be read or written to in the call. Otherwise there is undefined behavior. The only permitted operation in `foo` to modify `*v` value would be a `memcpy(v, /*...*/)`.

Instead you can do:

```
void foo(const void** v) {
    *v = /*...*/; // 1
    // or
    const void* x = *v; // 2
}
int main() {
    const void* d_ = nullptr;
    foo(&d);
    const char* d = static_cast<const char*>(d_);
}
```

Now the call to `foo` doesn't have the aliasing violation and `d` can be dereferenced, assuming `foo` has assigned `*v` a pointer to some object.

Answer (score 1):

Reinterpret cast should do the trick.

```
const char** ptr_char{};
const void** ptr_void{};

ptr_void = reinterpret_cast<const void**>(ptr_char);
```

In your case:

```
void foo(const void** v) {
}
int main() {
    const char* d = nullptr;
    foo(reinterpret_cast<const void**>(&d));
}
```